# How to revert multiple files (but not all) to a past commit?

Tags: git, revert

I need to revert a bunch of files (about 40-50) to a specific commit. However, I don't want to revert all the files. How do I do that without doing a per-file checkout for each of the files I need to revert? All the files I need to revert are located under a single folder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I already found out the solution.

```
git checkout master~1 ./FolderIWantToRevert ./AnotherFolderToRevert
```

Do note that I wanted to revert to the previous commit, that's why there's the `~1` after `master`.